# Get Native Thread Handle from C++11 Thread for Win32 API

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, c++11, winapi

I want to use some Win32 API functions from `windows.h` on a `std::thread`. To start things off, I am creating and starting a `std::thread`. Then I want to use a Win32 API function on it by getting the handle with `native_handle()`.

```cpp
// suspend_thread.cpp

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void foo()
{
    unsigned int counter = 1;
    while (counter <= 5)
    {
        // do some work and finish after about 5 seconds
        std::cout << "Running... " << counter << "/5" << std::endl;
        counter++;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Starting thread..." << std::endl;
    std::thread my_thread(foo);

    std::cout << "Waiting 3 seconds..." << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    DWORD result = SuspendThread((void*) my_thread.native_handle());
    if (result != -1) std::cout << "Successfully suspended thread!" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "Failed to suspend thread! Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

    my_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

If I don't cast the result of `native_handle()` to `void*` ...

`DWORD result = SuspendThread(my_thread.native_handle());`

... the code doesn't compile, because `SuspendThread()` expects a pointer.

`.\suspend_thread.cpp:25:57: error: invalid conversion from 'std::thread::native_handle_type' {aka 'unsigned int'} to 'HANDLE' {aka 'void*'} [-fpermissive]`

Now if I compile and run the first example, I get the following result.

```
PS> g++ -std=c++11 -pthread suspend_thread.cpp -o suspend_thread.exe
PS> ./suspend_thread.exe
Starting thread...
Waiting 3 seconds...
Running... 1/5
Running... 2/5
Running... 3/5
Failed to suspend thread! Error: 6
Running... 4/5
Running... 5/5
Done!
```

I tried to suspend the thread while it was running, however the function fails with the error code 6, which according to the documentation stands for ...

`ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE (0x6): The handle is invalid.`

... so apparently this is not the right way to pass a handle to a Win32 API function.

I know that I can pause and resume threads in another way without using the Win32 API.

Comment: [Why you should never suspend a thread](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031209-00/?p=41573).

Comment: `native_handle()` has no portable requirements whatsoever. If it exists it gives yo back something whose behavior is implementation defined. Don't try to guess what it does from its name. Read your compiler's documentation.

Comment: @PeteBecker: The [official Microsoft documentation on `std::thread::native_handle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/thread-class?view=vs-2019#native_handle) states that the return value represents a Win32 `HANDLE`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel -- the link you provide leads to this: "Returns the implementation-specific type that represents the thread handle. The thread handle can be used in implementation-specific ways.". I don't see where it says that it's a Windows `HANDLE`. I don't know if Microsoft has changed the code from what I wrote for Dinkumware (which is the library that MS shipped), but back in 2011 `native_handle_type` was **not** a Windows `HANDLE`. A `HANDLE` was not sufficient to implement all of the threading requirements at the time. Because of WinCE.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Did you read the section titled "Return Value" in my link? It states that the return type is defined as a "Win32 HANDLE".

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2017. Most of the time the program deadlocks. Sometimes I get the message "Successfully suspended thread!".  I never get the message "Failed to suspend thread!".

Comment: this is *g++* and may be it used different from *msvc* crt. where implementation of `native_handle()` return something else, but for *msvc* crt - `native_handle()` do `return _Thr._Hnd;` and `_Thr._Hnd = reinterpret_cast<void*>( _beginthreadex(...` so this is "real" object handle

Comment: @AndreasWenzel -- no, I didn't. <g> Note, however, that the question suggests that the code is being compiled with g++, not Microsoft's compiler. So Microsoft's documentation won't tell you what g++ does.

Comment: @pet Microsoft's `std::thread` implementation returns [`_Thr._Hnd`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1680ae7f0e6ffeb53ad3c51e8a8214d2a2d13c9a/stl/inc/thread#L136), where `_Hnd` is [initialized from `_beginthreadex`' return value](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1680ae7f0e6ffeb53ad3c51e8a8214d2a2d13c9a/stl/inc/thread#L64), so that's a native `HANDLE`. I'm curious, though, what *"threading requirements"* a native `HANDLE` can't provide. Can you explain?

Comment: @IInspectable -- I don't remember specifically, but the issue was with WinCE, where one of the operations required for `std::thread` needed something besides a `HANDLE`. So the internal implementation carried around two different thread identifiers, and `native_handle()` returned a pointer to that internal struct.